# Spring Boot Failed to load Application context error

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, model-view-controller, yaml, mockito

**In my Spring Boot app I am trying to run a simple test on my Service class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class DailyMoodLogServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    DailyMoodLogRepository moodLogRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        List<DailyMoodLog> dailyMoodSample = List.of(new DailyMoodLog(1L, "Good",
                Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()), "United States",
                new Users(1L, "John", "London")),
                new DailyMoodLog(2L, "Bad", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()
                ), "Canada", new Users(2L, "Anthony", "Wilkins")));
        Mockito.when(moodLogRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(dailyMoodSample);
    }

    @Test
    void getAllDailyMoods() {
        assertEquals(2, moodLogRepository.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

**ERROR RECEIVED**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@13579834 testClass = com.schwery.datawebapp.services.implementations.DailyMoodLogServiceImplTest, locations = [], classes = [com.schwery.datawebapp.DatawebappApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5824a83d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4d154ccd, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@a352e594, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2e8c1c9b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@5149d738, org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer@cb0755b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@f6463d3d], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException: Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location 'class path resource [application.yml]' is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile' [origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 10:13]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.lambda$throwIfPropertyFound$0(InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.throwIfPropertyFound(InvalidConfigDataPropertyException.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.checkForInvalidProperties(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.applyToEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:235)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
```

**YML FILE**

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  profiles:
    active: main
---
    spring:
      profiles: main

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
```

**I was told to put the datasource `password` `url` and `username` in the VM options, is this correctly done?**

I was also told I could put the placeholder values for the .YML File, in the either the environment variables, program arguments or VM options, but to just use the VM options, is that true?

[image]

**PROJECT STRUCTURE**

[image: File Structure]

Ive have tried to add the @WebAppConfiguration annotation to the test class, and also adding the @ApplicationContext.

**I also switched my .YML file to this with and without the `profiles: active: main` part**

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  profiles:
    active: main
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
---
spring:
  profiles: main

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
```

**After receiving this error**
`Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.config.InvalidConfigDataPropertyException: Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location 'class path resource [application.yml]' is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile' [origin: class path resource [application.yml] - 13:13]`

Thanks guys for taking the time to read this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for detailed information & nice formatting & highlighting the main statement of the error message!

And that, what it (error message) tries to propose:

`application.yml`

```yaml
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  profiles:
    active: main
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: main
  datasource:
    # ... the rest looks ok
```

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles

So

- `spring.profiles.active` is correct,up-to-date since spring-boot 2, it "activates profiles" (it can be done only in "profile-less" configuration/body/... or any other ["externalized configuration"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config))
- `spring.config.activate.on-profile` is the correct,up-to-date way to declare a configuration section as "profile(-base)d" (just as the name implies).
- `---` is a ["multi document separator"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.multi-document), which separates "default/no-profile" from "main" in that case.
- <del>`spring.profiles`</del> is outdated and raises the described exception.